# Sharpshooter Binomial Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

A skilled sharpshooter misses a mark $4$ percent of the time. Find the probabilities

$(1)$ He will miss at most $1$ mark in $15$ shots.

$(2)$ He will miss the mark for the first time on the sixth shot.

---

Binomial Distribution :

$$\sum^{1}_{x=0} b(x,15,,04) = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 15 \\0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)\cdot(.4)^0(1-.04)^{15-0}+ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 15 \\1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) \cdot(.4)^1(1-.04)^{15-1} $$

$$ \Rightarrow\sum^{1}_{x=0} b(x,15,,04) = .542+3.3880 = 3.9301$$

However the answer according to the book is $.8809$ ? Does anyone know where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: See that you have a typo (0.4 instead of 0.04).

Comment: Okay just my mistake then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first question seems to have been answered by the comment of *nicola*, I'll answer the second, which calls for the geometric distribution, since order matters.

With $p=0.04$, we have $$(1-p)^5p=0.0326\dots$$